# How to specify Mac platform in qmake (QtCreator)

Tags: macos, qt, qt4, qt5, qmake

I would like to set some configurations for Mac OS in `pro` file via QtCreator. I read the document, and found it supports Windows and Unix, like the following,

```
 win32 {
     SOURCES += hellowin.cpp
 }
 unix {
     SOURCES += hellounix.cpp
 }
```

I understand Mac OS is *nix-like OS, however, I still want to make difference with Linux. Is there a way to do this?

---

Ubuntu + Qt5.1

Comment: BTW, it's very important in Qt .pro file to have the brace `{` in the same line as the OS. If the brace goes in the next line, then it will not work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can detect Mac OS X this way:

```
macx {
    SOURCES += hellomac.cpp
}
```

But to make the difference with Linux you would rather like to specify

```
unix:!macx {
    SOURCES += hellolinux.cpp
}

macx: {
    SOURCES += hellomac.cpp
}
```

Comment: thanks, It works. just don't know why there is no `macx` details in qt official document. [qmake manual link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-manual.html). Marked & upvote

Comment: It is just documented elsewhere - [running qmake](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-running.html). `macx` is one of qmake's platform-specific specs.

Comment: thanks for your link. and would you please take a look at the **update**, I found a problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce that. I've tried to add four files - hellomac.cpp, hellolinux.cpp, otherfile_mac.cpp, otherfile_linux.cpp + project file like yours. Qmake recognizes the conditions for sources inclusion just fine in both Mac OS X (10.8.4) and Linux (Mint 15 in my case).

Comment: never mind, I also believe Qt should recognize the conditions. Just make sure I don't miss another points on qmake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dmitry: That is wrong. It is actually officially documented: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qmake/qmake-language.html#platform-scope-values

Comment: It's funny that for me, `unix:!macx` works, but `macx` or `mac` does not.

Answer (score 26):

'mac': it applies both on Mac OS X and iOS

'macx': it is specific to Mac OS X.

So, if you wanna include iOS support later, or simply be flexible (and why not?), you will better use 'mac'. Otherwise go for the latter. So you will need either of those.

Here you can find the official documentation:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qmake/qmake-language.html#platform-scope-values

Here are the variants you may need based on your specific use case.

#### mac (including iOS support)

```
win32 {
    SOURCES += hellolinux.cpp
} mac {
    SOURCES += hellomac.cpp
}
```

#### macx

```
win32 {
    SOURCES += hellolinux.cpp
} macx {
    SOURCES += hellomacx.cpp
}
```

Here you can find the source code to seek more information about undocumented scopes:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/730bc064a070e886e10950ccfd59780e8976f5fd:mkspecs